# manage image/video path for a later use

Tags: flutter

I would like to ask if there is any way to get an image path from the image gallery, and keep using the same path in the future? Here is the current procedure I have implemented:

- user picks an image from picker and sends it to other users
- the upload works, and shows the image from the gallery
- the problem is how can I keep displaying the same uploaded image from gallery without picking it again?

Comment: maybe you could copy the image file to your project, and access it from your project after user selected the image, something like how cache works?

Comment: Thats exactly what i did , i see my self duplicating images and videos .

Answer (score 0):

As [xion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2281066/xion) commented you can store or copy image to any variable in flutter and use it in future, and if you want image path then you can use something like this

```
Future openPicker() async{
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      //this is your image
      _image = image;

      //this is Image path
      imagePath = _image.path
    });
  }
```

Now **imagePath** variable has value of image path and you can use it anytime.
[TechWithVP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13857463/techwithvp)

Comment: Thanks for answer , but stocking the image in variable wont solve my issue , the task am willing to achive is like on chat applications , when you send photo to some  user , you can display the photo after words, i tried saving the path of image to database than retreive it for display, but the path change every time (i think for security reasons)

Comment: You can do 1 thing, when you pick image from gallery upload it as well on to the server, then store server image path to database.

Now your image is uploaded to server and you have url of it, so u can use it to any user with yr chat application, when u access that image on other user side use Image.network("give server image path").

I Hope this will solve yr problem

Comment: thanks for the hint , i looked deeply into this and i found that i cant use the same path either as you said upload it to server and access it from there or as xion said , save image to application folder and display it from there .